# Why are for...of and for loop behaving differently?

Tags: javascript

Just was performing simple task in JS which was to take integer as an input, divide it into single digits and multiply them ignoring all zeros in it.

I have solved it but had some troubles which were simply solved by changing the loop. I am just curious why the code did not work properly with the for loop and started to work as I it for for of loop. I could not find out the answer by my self. If somebody could tell where I am wrong.

First one works as intended, second one always returns 1.

```js
function digitsMultip1(data) {
  var stringg = data.toString().split("", data.lenght);
  for (let elements of stringg) {
    if (elements != 0) {
      sum = parseInt(elements) * sum
    } else {
      continue
    };
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(digitsMultip1(12035))


function digitsMultip2(data) {
  var sum = 1;
  var stringg = data.toString().split("", data.lenght);
  for (var i = 0; i > stringg.lenght; i++) {
    if (stringg[i] != 0) {
      sum = parseInt(stringg[i]) * sum
    } else {
      continue
    };
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(digitsMultip2(12035))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: `data.lenght` is spelled `data.length`, but split only takes one parameter anyway

Comment: There is no difference between a `for` loop and `for..of` loop *in the way that you are trying to use them*. Even if we are to assume the code is correct of spelling an logic mistakes.

Comment: You have misspelled length and used > sign instead of < sign. Please refer the 1st answer as correct answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no big difference. [for..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) works in newer browsers

> The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, Array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.

Several typos

length spelled wrong

`>` (greater than) should be `<` (less than) in your for loop

Now they both work

```js
function digitsMultip1(data) {
  var sum=1, stringg = data.toString().split("");
  for (let elements of stringg) {
    if (elements != 0) {
      sum *= parseInt(elements)
    } else {
      continue
    };
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(digitsMultip1(12035))


function digitsMultip2(data) {
  var sum = 1, stringg = data.toString().split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < stringg.length; i++) {
    if (stringg[i] != 0) {
      sum *= parseInt(stringg[i]) 
    } else {
      continue
    };
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(digitsMultip2(12035))
```

You might want to look at [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => { 
  currentValue = +currentValue || 1; return accumulator *= currentValue 
}

console.log(String(12035).split("").reduce(reducer,1));
```